# Does carrierwave support git/svn as a storage repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

1. Does carrierwave support git/svn as a storage repository instead of the file operating system.
2. Does carrierwave support versioning of an image. i.e. I stored foo.png / version1 and I made some changes and store foo.png / version2. So given foo.png we should be able to retrieve version1/version2.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://rubydoc.info/gems/carrierwave/frames

If you want to change your storage directory:

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def store_dir
    'public/my/upload/directory' #where you want to story images, also works for cloud storage
  end
end
```

If you want version control, using a thumbnail as an example:

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  process :resize_to_fit => [800, 800]

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [200,200]
  end

end
```

The rubydocs have all this information and more so check it out.

Another resource is Ryan Bates Rails Casts:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads - free

http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3 - requires subscription

Comment: That's another kind of version control :)

Comment: I'm assuming he uploads an original image, wants to do processing on it and keep both versions.